# Ninject constructor with delegate

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have classes which take delegates that return objects something like this:

```
public class ApiAuditor : IAuditor
{
    public Func<FooAPI> ApiGet { get; private set; }

    public ApiAuditor(Func<FooAPI> apiGet)
    {
        ApiGet = apiGet;
    }

    public bool Audit(Audit[] audits)
    {
        if(someCondition)
           return false; //no need for FooAPI
        return ApiGet().AuditJobs(audits);
    }

}
```

The idea being is that some of these classes  might need an instance of an object (FooAPI in this case) but not always. So they are injected as a delegate that can return an instance if required.

Using Ninject I just wanted to see if binding this type like this is the best approach?

```
Bind<IAuditor>().ToMethod(c => new ApiAuditor(() => c.Kernel.Get<FooAPI>()));
```

### Update

To elaborate a little more, I guess part of my problem is that I have been using Bind.WithConstructorArgument() whenever constructor arguments require some explicit resolving. I guess I could still use it, but it's less readable as it would end up something like:

```
Bind<IAuditor>().To<ApiAuditor>().WithConstructorArgument("apiGet", x => ( (Func<FooAPI>)(() => x.Kernel.Get<FooAPI>())));
```

Comment: Is: Bind<IAuditor>().ToMethod(c => new ApiAuditor(() => c.Kernel.Get<FooAPI>())) the best way to configure Ninject to resolve the dependency of the delegate? Basically is using a lambda that calls the kernel a good approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent wiring up instances yourself. You can do the following:

```
kernel.Bind<IApiAuditor>().To<ApiAuditor>();
kernel.Bind<Func<FooAPI>>().ToConstant(() => kernel.Get<FooAPI>()));
```

Note that you should usually not be worried about injecting instances that aren't used. The performance penalty is usually neglectable, so you should simply create the following constructor instead:

```
public ApiAuditor(FooAPI foo)
{
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

This makes your registration easier:

```
Bind<IApiAuditor>().To<ApiAuditor>();
Bind<FooAPI>().ToSelf();
```

Comment: Yes I like that, thanks. With regard to injecting instances that aren't used, I think it really depends on what those dependencies are. In this case it was worth it.

Comment: Actually that doesn't really work as no IContext is available in ToConstant(). So something like this is required: Bind<Func<FooAPI>>().ToMethod(x => ((Func<FooAPI>>)(() => x.Kernel.Get<FooAPI>>())));

Comment: @J_B: See my update. You can always get back to the container.